# There's a count difference between Druid Native Query and Druid SQL when using query

Tags: sql, json, druid

I have a problem with Druid Query.

I wanted to get data count with hour granularity.

So, I used Druid SQL like this.

```
SELECT TIME_FLOOR(__time, 'PT1H') AS t, count(1) AS cnt FROM mydatasource GROUP BY 1
```

then I got response like this.

```
[
  {
    "t": "2022-08-31T09:00:00.000Z",
    "cnt": 12427
  },
  {
    "t": "2022-08-31T10:00:00.000Z",
    "cnt": 16693
  },
  {
    "t": "2022-08-31T11:00:00.000Z",
    "cnt": 16694
  },
  ...
```

But, When using native query like this,

```
{
  "queryType": "timeseries",
  "dataSource": "mydatasource",
  "intervals": "2022-08-31T07:01Z/2022-09-01T07:01Z",
  "granularity": {
    "type": "period",
    "period": "PT1H",
    "timeZone": "Etc/UTC"
  },
  "aggregations": [
    {
      "name": "count",
      "type": "longSum",
      "fieldName": "count"
    }
  ],
  "context": {
    "skipEmptyBuckets": "true"
  }
}
```

There's a difference result.

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2022-08-31T09:00:00.000Z",
    "result": {
        "count": 1288965
    }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2022-08-31T10:00:00.000Z",
    "result": {
        "count": 1431215
    }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2022-08-31T11:00:00.000Z",
    "result": {
        "count": 1545258
    }
  },
  ...
```

I want to use the result of Native Query.

What's the problem in my Druid SQL query??

How do I create a query to get native query results?

---

I found what's difference.

when using longSum type aggregation, I get result like native query.

So, I want to know how to query aggregate like below using sql.

```
"aggregations": [
  {
    "type": "longSum",
    "name": "count",
    "fieldName": "count"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

Query like this.

```
SELECT TIME_FLOOR(__time, 'PT1H') AS t, sum("count") AS cnt FROM mydatasource GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Given that your datasource has a "count" column, I'm assuming it comes from an ingestion that uses rollup. This means that the original raw rows have been aggregated and the "count" column contains the count of raw rows that were summarized into the each aggregate row.

The Native query is using the longSum function over the "count" column.
The original SQL you used, is just counting the aggregate rows.

So yes, the correct way to get the count of raw rows is `SUM("count")`.